# What is the rationale when the Ratio Test is inconclusive?

Tags: sequences-and-series

limit of |$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$| = L

If L<1, then series converges

If L>1, then series diverges

If L=1, then inconclusive

I understand that taking the ratio mimics a geometric series.  So, if ratio approaches > 1 then diverges, and vice versa.

But, what is the deal when the ratio  limit = 1 ?   Why inconclusive?    My notes say, "Limit approaching 1 from above or below?"

If the ratio is approaching 1, then the terms are becoming the same, right?  Wouldn't that mean you're adding something each time, hence divergent?  Oh, wait, we're looking at abs value.  That could mean we're adding an amount each time, if all terms are (+), so diverging, but if we're alternating signs, then we are adding and subtracting the same number, thereby converging?   Is that the right idea?

Comment: Consider $\sum 1/n$ versus $\sum (-1)^n/n$.  One converges.  The other does not.  Both satisfy $|a_n / a_{n+1}| \to 1$.

Comment: The reason why the ratio test is inconclusive when $L = 1$ is because there exist both convergent and divergent series which satisfy this case. For example, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ approaches $1$ for all p-series.  However, a p-series is convergent when $p > 1$ and divergent when $p \leq 1$.

Comment: The reason that the test is inconclusive in the case that $L=1$ is in the proof.  The essential idea of the proof is to compare $\sum a_n$ to the series $\sum r^n$ (where the ratio between consecutive terms is $r$).  When $|r| < 1$, the series converges; when $|r| > 1$, the series diverges; but if $|r|=1$, the series converges if $r=-1$, but diverges if $r=1$.  So the ratio test is inconclusive.

Comment: Your logic is in correct direction. If $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_{n+1}/a_n|=1$ this means that $|a_n|$ is essentially the same as $|a_{n+1}|$, so you could conclude that $\lim |a_n|=a$ exists. If $a\neq 0$, then of course your sequence is divergent (in convergent sequence $a_n$ you will always have $\lim a_n =0$). So the only case for which you cannot directly say if sequence is converging or diverging is when $\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_{n+1}/a_n|=1$ and $\lim a_n =0$. As previous answers show, considering $a_n=1/n$, or $a_n=1/n^2$ gives two examples where one sequence diverges and other converges.

Comment: Thanks for the examples.  Now makes sense!